# Get max value and max date from sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table with duplicate member names but these duplicates also have more than one date and a specific ID.  I want the row of the member name with the most recent date (because a member could have been called more than one time a day) and biggest CallID number.

```
MemberID    FirstName     LastName     CallDate     CallID
 0123         Carl         Jones      2019-03-01    123456
 0123         Carl         Jones      2020-10-12    215789
 0123         Carl         Jones      2020-10-12    312546
 2045        Sarah         Marty      2021-05-09    387945
 2045        Sarah         Marty      2021-08-11    398712
 4025         Jane         Smith      2021-10-18    754662
 4025         Jane         Smith      2021-11-03    761063
 8282         Suzy         Aaron      2019-12-12    443355
 8282         Suzy         Aaron      2019-12-12    443386
```

So the desired output from this table would be

```
MemberID    FirstName     LastName     CallDate     CallID
 0123         Carl         Jones      2020-10-12    312546
 2045        Sarah         Marty      2021-08-11    398712
 4025         Jane         Smith      2021-11-03    761063
 8282         Suzy         Aaron      2019-12-12    443386
```

The query I've tried is

```
SELECT DISTINCT MemberID, FirstName, LastName, MAX(CallDate) as CallDate, MAX(CallID) as CallID
FROM dbo.table 
GROUP BY MemberID, FirstName, LastName, CallDate, CallID 
ORDER BY LastName asc;
```

But I'm still getting duplicate names with all their calldates and CallID

Comment: You can accomplish this with [window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/). What SQL servers are you using? MySQL? Postgresql? Microsoft?

Comment: Or you can add ` HAVING CallID=MAX(CallID)`, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:~:text=The-,HAVING,-clause%2C%20like%20the

Comment: @Luuk, using ```HAVING CallID = MAX(CallID)``` gives me the same table as just calling the ```max``` in the ```select```.

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Not specifically your question, but you'll do better in general if you normalize your databases at least through third normal form. Your example violates first normal form by including member IDs *and* names in each row. You could fix this by moving your names to a child table keyed by member ID, and using a JOIN in your query, so your main table contains only the information about calls, and the information about members (names, and/or whatever else you want to track) is in a table just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing CallDate, CallID  from the group by clause.

So :

```
SELECT MemberID, FirstName, LastName, MAX(CallDate) as CallDate, MAX(CallID) as CallID

FROM dbo.table 
GROUP BY MemberID, FirstName, LastName 

ORDER BY LastName asc;
```

Hopefully that should do it.

Comment: and remove the `DISTINCT`..... (which I did do...)

Comment: @Luuk true the group by essentially makes the DISTINCT moot

Comment: here is the db fiddle link incase you want to check things out.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4SccyjMQuGqjcB4dPob2Xs/0

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by MemberID order by CallID desc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```